Is there a grafana plugin that lets me interact with the display
I am trying to use grafana with postgresql for my test automation system. Let's say I have 2 test suites that each have 2 test cases (A.1 A.2 B.1 B.2) that are getting executed everyday. I have a system in place for adding the new test results into my postgresql database and I was wondering if there is a plugin that shows The passed/failed test suites and if i click on the failed one it shows the status of the test cases in that suite. Are there these kinds of interactive plugins?

Don't know if something like that exists as plugin, but I'm pretty sure you can achieve similar results with Stat panel, variable and data links
